# How to add shortcut hint in MenuBar items in Qt/QML 6

Tags: qml, pyside6, qt6

I'm looking for a way to add the shortcut hint to a Menu item into the red square as shown on the picture:

[image: Expected result]

It should say "Usage guide" on the left and "F1" on the right. However, in Qt6 I cannot find a way to do this, because [MenuItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls-menuitem.html) as compared to Qt5 doesn't have `shortcut` property anymore.

This is my code that doesn't show the shortcut:

```
Menu {
    id: helpMenu
    title: "&Help"

    Action {
        text: "Usage guide"
        shortcut: "F1"
    }
}
```

However, using a delegate on Menu, I can force it to display more information:

```
Menu {
    id: helpMenu
    title: "&Help"
    delegate: MenuItem {
        id: control

        contentItem: Rectangle {
            anchors.centerIn: parent

            Text {
                text: control.text
                anchors.left: parent.left
            }

            Text {
                text: "F1"
                anchors.right: parent.right
            }
        }
    }

    Action {
        text: "Usage guide"
        shortcut: "F1"
    }
}
```

but here I don't know how to pass the shortcut from an Action into the delegate. It only works for text. I can hardcode the text in there, but that's not useful.

Comment: You could use this https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qt-labs-platform-menuitem.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically your solution, but using [Shortcut](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-shortcut.html) to convert the [standard keyboard shortcuts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qkeysequence.html#StandardKey-enum) into a string.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Menu {
        id: contextMenu
        title: "&Help"

        Action {
            text: "Usage guide"
            shortcut: "F1"
        }
        Action {
            text: "Cut"
            shortcut: StandardKey.Copy
        }
        Action {
            text: "Copy"
            shortcut: "Ctrl+E,Ctrl+W"
        }
        Action { text: "Paste" }

        delegate: MenuItem {
            id: control

            contentItem: Item {
                anchors.centerIn: parent

                Text {
                    text: control.text
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    color: "white"
                }

                Shortcut {
                    id: shortcutHelper
                    sequence: control.action.shortcut
                }

                Text {
                    text: shortcutHelper.nativeText
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    color: "white"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: contextMenu.open()
}
```

---

After reading a bit about shortcuts and standard keyboard shortcuts I found this [bugreport](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-96350). The solution I came up with outputs a warning which says to use `sequences` for standard keyboard shortcuts instead of `sequence` as there could be multiple shortcuts assigned to a standard keyboard shortcut.

> QML Shortcut: Shortcut: Only binding to one of multiple key bindings
> associated with 9. Use 'sequences: [  ]' to bind to all of them.

So for your purpose this would be sufficient:

```
Menu {
    id: contextMenu
    title: "&Help"

    Action {
        text: "Usage guide"
        shortcut: "F1"
    }

    delegate: MenuItem {
        id: control

        contentItem: Item {
            anchors.centerIn: parent

            Text {
                text: control.text
                anchors.left: parent.left
                color: "white"
            }

            Text {
                text: control.action.shortcut
                anchors.right: parent.right
                color: "white"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would one allow the action to accept alt-shortcuts as well?  Using this approach if I prepend with & in the text, it appears verbatim in the display with no alt key functionality